# Wicket Form: ERROR - Unable to write file

Tags: java, tomcat, wicket

I am having problems with my file Upload form in wicket. I am not being able of uploading any file into the online server.

This script worked already, but for some time it stopped.

So I search for answers, but I was getting the same error.

My code is equal to: http://www.mkyong.com/wicket/wicket-file-upload-example/ 
The difference is the folder path isn't local as it is in the example but points to a remote url via https.

Additional information:

- Server

  - Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux 7 (wheezy)
  - Tomcat: Tomcat 7
  - Permissions in taget folder: 777
- Local:

  - Tomcat: Tomcat 7
  - JDK: 1.7
  - Wicket: 6

Test

1. Open upload site
2. Select file aa.png(It doesn't exists in the server)
3. Press upload

Result:

```
28 10 13 18:19:31:630 - ERROR - Unable to write file


java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)

28 10 13 18:27:02:370 - ERROR - Unexpected error occurred
org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: Method onFormSubmitted of interface 

org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.IFormSubmitListener 
targeted at [Form [Component id = form]] on component [Form [Component id = form]] `threw an exception`

Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.
internalInvoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:258)
... 30 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error
at com.myproject.presentation.utils.examples.FileUploadPage$1.onSubmit(FileUploadPage.java:51)
at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form$9.component(Form.java:1246)
at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form$9.component(Form.java:1240)
at org.apache.wicket.util.visit.Visits.visitPostOrderHelper(Visits.java:274)
at org.apache.wicket.util.visit.Visits.visitPostOrder(Visits.java:245)
at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.delegateSubmit(Form.java:1239)
at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.process(Form.java:921)
at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.onFormSubmitted(Form.java:767)
at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.onFormSubmitted(Form.java:700)
... 35 more
```

Comment: StackOverflow is a place for posting code, not links to code.

Comment: For one, as no one can tell what's at line 51 of your FileUploadPage.java we'll have to guess that's the line where you catch an exception, throw it and any usefull information contained, away and throw a new one. Grabbing code from random sites and using it without understanding what it does is a really bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

From the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File%28java.net.URI%29) of File:

> public File(URI uri)
>
> Creates a new File instance by converting the given file: URI into an
>   abstract pathname.
>
> The exact form of a file: URI is system-dependent, hence the
>   transformation performed by this constructor is also system-dependent.
>
> For a given abstract pathname f it is guaranteed that
>
> ```
> new File( f.toURI()).equals( f.getAbsoluteFile())
> ```
>
> so long as the original abstract pathname, the URI, and the new
>   abstract pathname are all created in (possibly different invocations
>   of) the same Java virtual machine. This relationship typically does
>   not hold, however, when a file: URI that is created in a virtual
>   machine on one operating system is converted into an abstract pathname
>   in a virtual machine on a different operating system.
>
> Parameters:
>
> uri - An absolute, hierarchical URI with a scheme equal to "file", a non-empty path component, and undefined authority, query, and fragment components
>
> Throws:
>
> NullPointerException - If uri is null
>
> IllegalArgumentException - If the preconditions on the parameter do not hold
>
> Since:
>   1.4

No one said anything about http or https.